# Package a library project which uses another library aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, aar

I am creating a library project (lets say B) and I have a dependency for another library (lets say A) which I have in the form of an aar (e.g. a.aar) file. Now the problem here is we can directly use a.aar files in an Application project but for using it with a library project, I have to first add it as a different module.

My question here is, after building the project when the b.aar is generated, will the a.aar file be packaged inside b.aar file? or will I have to share both a.aar and b.aar to the app developer?

Comment: It seems can't,I've tried several hours and I'm failed.

Comment: I'd suggest to upload the library that your library is using to Maven, or other repository, and make that dependency transitive

Comment: You can generate `fat aar` to solve this. Follow steps in https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar this link

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies of a Android Library Project will not be bundled within the aar of the library. 
When someone else adds your library as a dependency, the dependencies of your library will need to included in the parent project.

In short, you need to share your aar dependency with the application developer who will use your library.

Comment: Thanks Orkunsoylu, Was hoping after all this time this functionality should have been added